# Ansible replace: regex/replace span multiple lines?

Tags: ansible

In ansible, I'd like to replace this:

```
  <sadmin>
    <user>admin@localhost</user>
  </sadmin>
```

with this:

```
<sadmin>
   <user>user1@somedomain</user>
   <user>user2@somedomain</user>
   <user>user3@somedomain</user>
 </sadmin>
```

I've tried using the replace module, but don't know if the regex can span multiple lines (how would I use python raw notation for newlines?). I tried the `xml` module but I don't think this is actually an XML file since it kept adding a `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>` header to the top of the file. How can I do this? Better to use a template?

```
  - name: add replacements to jabber config files
    replace:
      path   : "/etc/jabberd2/{{ item.path }}"
      regexp : "{{ item.regex }}"
      replace: "{{ item.replace }}"
    with_items:
      - { path: 'muc.xml', regex: 'conference.localhost', replace: 'conference.mydomain' }
      - { path: 'muc.xml', regex: '<sadmin>.*</sadmin>',      replace: '<sadmin><user>user1@somedomain</user>\n<user>user2@somedomain</user></sadmin>' }
```

Comment: I believe that using the `xml` module shoudl give you the cleanest results. Did you check if the xml header does any harm to jabber? If not I would recommed to go with the xml module. Otherwise you might want to check if the [blockinfile module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html) could be used here.

Comment: Is there a good reason that you can't generate this file from scratch and use the template mechanism instead?

Comment: The templates work well but then everytime a new version of the software comes along I have to `vimdiff` my templates. It seems less hassle to just maintain a few `lineinfile` directives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The play below does what is requested

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: test.xml
        regexp: '<user>admin@localhost<\/user>'
        replace: |-
          <user>user1@somedomain</user>
            <user>user2@somedomain</user>
            <user>user3@somedomain</user>
```

The next example below shows how to replace the whole *sadmin* section

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: test.xml
        regexp: '(<sadmin>[\s\S]*)</sadmin>'
        replace: |-
          <sadmin>
            <user>user1@somedomain</user>
            <user>user2@somedomain</user>
            <user>user3@somedomain</user>
          </sadmin>
```

Comment: That is good but is there a way to match all  within the `<sadmin>.*</sadmin>` block? It would be best to remove whatever exists in between those tags and have ansible rewrite with the wanted values. This helps when re-applying an updated playbook

Comment: Sure, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I could not figure out the right `regexp` to get it working. Yours works great.